# What's wrong with this code?

Tags: c, return-value, precision

In the following code a strange thing is happening. The function get_time_in_seconds(), a custom function I have built and tested independently, works fine when called directly from inside the long printf statement. However, it does not store the expected value when I assign it to the variable curr_time2. Any guesses why?

```
while (1)
{
    count++;
    bytes_read = recvfrom(sock,recv_data,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, (socklen_t*)&addr_len);
  recv_data[bytes_read] = '\0';
  strcpy(buff,inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr));
    printf("\nAt %lf (%s , %d, Num : %d) said : ",get_time_in_seconds(),buff,ntohs(client_addr.sin_port),get_id(buff));
    printf("%s", recv_data);
    curr_time2=get_time_in_seconds();
    printf("%lf\n",curr_time2);
//      data.nodeid=get_id(buff);
//      data.time = curr_time2;
    //printf("%f,%f\n",data.time,curr_time2);
    store_packetdata(&data);
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Sample output:

> At 1303829191.827888 (10.22.6.162 ,
>   35355, Num : 1) said : 505
>   1303829248.000000
>
> At 1303829196.827893 (10.22.6.162 ,
>   35355, Num : 1) said : 506
>   1303829248.000000
>
> At 1303829201.827898 (10.22.6.162 ,
>   35355, Num : 1) said : 507
>   1303829248.000000
>
> At 1303829206.827903 (10.22.6.162 ,
>   35355, Num : 1) said : 508
>   1303829248.000000
>
> At 1303829211.827908 (10.22.6.162 ,
>   35355, Num : 1) said : 509
>   1303829248.000000
>
> At 1303829216.827913 (10.22.6.162 ,
>   35355, Num : 1) said : 510
>   1303829248.000000
>
> At 1303829221.827918 (10.22.6.162 ,
>   35355, Num : 1) said : 511
>   1303829248.000000
>
> At 1303829226.827923 (10.22.6.162 ,
>   35355, Num : 1) said : 512
>   1303829248.000000
>
> At 1303829231.827928 (10.22.6.162 ,
>   35355, Num : 1) said : 513
>   1303829248.000000

At 1303829236.827933 (10.22.6.162 , 35355, Num : 1) said : 514
1303829248.000000

At 1303829241.827938 (10.22.6.162 , 35355, Num : 1) said : 515
1303829248.000000

EDIT: I have now solved the problem. Initially both curr_time2 and return type of get_time_in_sconds() were in float. When I converted both to double the code started working. However, what I want to know is why printf() was printing accurate while curr_time2 was storing only an approximation of the value.

New Declarations (change double to float for old ones).

```
double get_time_in_seconds()
{
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    double retval= (double)tv.tv_sec + ((double)tv.tv_sec)/1000000;
    return retval;
}
    static double curr_time2=0.0;
```

Comment: @apoorv020: can you post your get_time_in_second function and the declaration of curr_time2 ?

Comment: what type is curr_time2? What data type does get_time_in_seconds() return?

Comment: @Overbose: Solved the problem. I converted both the return type and curr_time2 to double from float and it worked.

Comment: @apoorv020: is curr_time2 of the same type as the return value from get_time_in_second()?

Comment: Show more declarations, what is the type of the curr_time2 variable? How is the get_time_in_seconds() function declared?

Comment: @apoorv020: don't convert values with casts (eg `(double)get_time_in_seconds()`). Usually, casts indicate some bad design decision or error in your code.

Comment: Also you almost never want to use `float` variables / functions. In the absence of a strong reason to do otherwise, `double` should be used.

Comment: You're using `tv_sec` twice rather than `tv_sec` and `tv_usec`....

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the type of `curr_time2` I can only guess, but it seems to be declared integer and not float.

If that wasn't the case please post more code (the function and argument declarations), because at the moment I can not do any more then this guess.

Answer (score 1):

**after the edit**

> > why printf() was printing accurate

The function `printf()` is a variadic function.
Arguments "suffer" default conversions: basically `char` and `short` to `int`; `float` to `double`.

In your code

```
printf("%lf", float_value);
```

the `float_value` is automagically converted to `double` and the `%lf` conversion specification is treated the same as `%f` in C99 (`"%lf"` is an error in C89) which expects a `double` value.

Comment: But should not the function have returned a float value, losing precision before printf used the value?

Comment: I guess it should lose precision. I couldn't find a relevant passage in the Standard though. *On a small test file, gcc (and [ideone compiler](http://ideone.com/8hihD)) behaved as expected, losing precision*.

Answer (score 1):

Most C compilers won't actually pass `float` values as parameters or return them from functions -- they'll silently be converted to `double` for that.  So when you were directly passing the return value of `get_time_in_seconds()` to `printf`, it was done in double precision.  However, when you stored it in the `float` variable `curr_time2` it would convert it to single precision for the store and back to double precision to pass to printf.

Note that the above is allowed behavior by the spec, but not required behavior -- the C compiler is always allowed (by the spec) to use extra precision for intermediate values such as function parameters and return values